# Search comma seperated text in Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene

How to search a text in Lucene which has comma in it ?
Example:

> search?_s=(display_name==App America, Inc)

Here, I want to search **App America, Inc**. But it doesn't work

SOLR version : 5.5.0

Comment: What is the type of the field? What is that syntax build on? A Solr query would be `q=display_name:"App America, Inc"`. Is this the only value in the field? If that's the case - the field type should probably be just a string to only get an exact match.

Comment: `search?_s=(display_name==App America, Inc)` what kind of code it is?